# Quickblox Android: querying customObject with QBRequestBuilder

Tags: android, quickblox

Let's suppose I have a customObject class named "MyCustomObject" that have two fields: "field_a" and "field_b".

What is the equivalent (using the QBRequest builder) of:

```
 Select * From MyCustomObject Where (field_a = val1 AND field_b = val2) OR (field_a = val2 AND field_b = val1)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
QBRequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
requestBuilder.or("field_a", "val1", "val2")

QBCustomObjects.getObjects("MyCustomObject", requestBuilder, new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBCustomObject>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBCustomObject> customObjects, Bundle params) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {

    }
});
```

more info is here what's possible
https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-android#With_filters

Comment: This is not the equivalent of what I'm looking for